# RxJs: Цепочка Observable внутри scan оператора

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

Есть массив неких действий, пусть будет ['a1','a2','a3','a4']. b1, b2, b3, b4 - их результаты. Каждое действие - Observable.
Подразумевается, что это действия над неким DTO, и каждое действие делает что-то с DTO. Также есть требование - результат каждого предыдущего действия в scan (или альтернативном операторе?), должен эмиттится следующему действию, именно это у меня и не получается. На вход каждой итерации подается аккумулятор - observable, который по идее должен дать текущему действию результат предыдущего, т.к в прошлом действии к аккумулятору был добавлен новый pipe, возвращающий результат предыдущего действия, **но это не срабатывает**, аккумулятор на входе всегда является заданным seed без результата предыдущего действия. Порядок действий важен, т.е a2 всегда ждет, пока не выполнится a1 и т.д, а на выходе из scan должен быть результат a4 (В продакшине вместо строк будут объекты - разные Dto, получаемые как результаты действий над ними - http запросы на создание/обновление/удаление DTO)

Подскажите, что я не так делаю. Код ниже иллюстрирует проблему. Я пробовал различные комбинации операторов, в том числе mergeScan, который вроде как предназначен для того, что мне нужно, но не гарантирует порядок выполнения действий.

Поиграть с кодом можно в онлайн редакторе [тут](https://stackblitz.com/edit/observable-switchmap-67bxqh). Спасибо!

```
const b1 = of("b1").pipe(delay(1000));
const b2 = of("b2").pipe(delay(2000));
const b3 = of("b3").pipe(delay(500));
const b4 = of("b4").pipe(delay(100));

from(['a1','a2','a3','a4']).pipe(
  concatMap(action => of(action).pipe(
    scan((acc: Observable<string>, a: string) => {
      switch(a) {
        case 'a1':
        return acc.pipe(
          tap(x => console.log(`before map a1: ${x}`)),
          concatMap(a => b1),
          tap(x => console.log(`after map a1: ${x}`)),
        )
        case 'a2':
        return acc.pipe(
          tap(x => console.log(`before map a2: ${x}`)),
          //  Ожидается в tap выше получить результат a1
          concatMap(a => b2),
          tap(x => console.log(`after map a2: ${x}`)),
        )
        case 'a3':
        return acc.pipe(
          tap(x => console.log(`before map a3: ${x}`)),
          //  Ожидается в tap выше получить результат a2
          concatMap(a => b3),
          tap(x => console.log(`after map a3: ${x}`)),
        )
        case 'a4':
        return acc.pipe(
          tap(x => console.log(`before map a4: ${x}`)),
          //  Ожидается в tap выше получить результат a3
          concatMap(a => b4),
          tap(x => console.log(`after map a4: ${x}`)),
        )
      }
      return acc;
    }, of('')
  )
  )

// Вывод:

before map a1:

after map a1: b1

Subscribe: b1

before map a2:

after map a2: b2

Subscribe: b2

before map a3:

after map a3: b3

Subscribe: b3

before map a4:

after map a4: b4

Subscribe: b4
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было убрать верхний concatMap и для получения в subscribe последнего результата добавить в конец операторы last() и flatMap(x => x), тогда scan аккумулирует в себе результат всех цепочек observable и вернет результат последнего.